# Using Adobe Flash on iOS devices

Tags: ios, flash

Is there any way through which a flash content can be run on iOS devices?

I am getting two different view.

The link below says that it is possible that we can develop some flash application and run it on iOS devices.

http://www.adobe.com/inspire/2012/12/ios-apps-flash-cs6.html

But on the Apple website link it says running flash applications is not possible on iOS devices.

Can someone clarify if it is possible to run the flash applications on iOS?

Comment: here is the link from Apple https://www.apple.com/hotnews/thoughts-on-flash/

Comment: Based on http://flashgamer.com/blog/comments/apple-is-not-currently-accepting-applications-built-with-air-3.9 it seems that you can run it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run flash natively on iOS devices. Adobe does, however, provide a tool to run software built with flash on iOS devices.

This works in a similar way to Cordova/ Phonegap in that it takes your code and crosscompiles it into iOS code using other plugins and librarys.

As shown here:
http://www.infoworld.com/article/2623251/mobile-development/escape-the-ios-sdk--building-iphone--and-android--apps-via-flash.html

Answer (score 0):

Safari on Mac OS will support Flash

Safari on iOS won’t support Flash.
We will need to write a native iOS app to deliver the functionality